# Getting value from certain unnamed table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have page with multiple messy tables, and i need to read few certain values and put them in js variables.
How would i read value from second if they are all unnamed and they don't have any id's?

```
<table>
<tbody> <tr>
<td>...
<td>...
<td>...
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tbody> <tr>
<td>...
<td>...
<td>...
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tbody> <tr>
<td>...
<td>...
<td>...
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector` and use a `:nth-child(n)` selector to indicate with *n* which one you want to get. This also works with `tr` and `td` of course.

Here we select the second table, its first row, its third cell:

```js
let val = document.querySelector("table:nth-child(2) tr td:nth-child(3)")
                  .textContent;

console.log(val);
```

```html
<table>
<tbody> <tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tbody> <tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>this value</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tbody> <tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide some feed-back? Did this answer your question?